# Spring won't intercept locale parameter + security [Java, i18n]

Tags: java, security, spring, internationalization

I am using both Spring security and Spring i18n. This is my security config:

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/denied.htm">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?login_error=true" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied.htm" filters="none"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" filters="none"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

    <security:logout/>
</security:http>
```

Besides that, I have set `authenticationManager` for database with MD5 encoding for password. Security work just fine. My i18n config is:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

It works fine with reading locales from web browser's HTTP request, but I want it to change locale if I click on the link on the page (adds `?lang=hr` parameter to current page). So when I add this, locale doesn't change at all:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**So I have few questions.**

1. Why the locale interception suddenly doesn't work and how to fix it?
2. How to **read the current chosen locale for user's session** from java class? I have java class where I need to fetch spring's message from `message_en.properties` or `message_hr.properties` file. Jasper report.
3. I need to add some interceptor (or something like that) to restrain user with default password only to work with `/changePassword.htm` page. What is the simplest solution?

Many thanks

Comment: For future questions, please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Are your controllers really mapped with `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`?

Comment: @Ralph Sorry about multiple questions. @axtavt I don't understand your question. There is handlerMapping bean. One of my controllers looks like this: 
 @RequestMapping("/change.htm")
 public ModelAndView change(@RequestParam("oldPassword") String oldPassword,
          @RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword){
... }

Comment: so it doesn't expect the "lang" parameter. Is this a problem? I thought Spring automatically recognizes lang parameter since it is defined in localeChangeInterceptor bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why the locale interception suddenly doesn't work and how to fix
>      it?

I guess: To "fix" you local interceptor, you should check, that the local interceptor can be invoked even if the user is not logged in.

> _2. How to read the current chosen locale for user's session from java
>   class?

Use the `RequestContext.getLocale()` method.
@see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver

**added**
The best place (in design/architecure) to obtain the local form the request is the web controller. If you are using Spring 3.0 you can obtain the `HttpServletRequest` directly if you put an parameter of this type to your Controller Request Handler Method. But you have an better choise: **just add a `Local` parameter to your controller handler method**
@see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments

> _3. I need to add some interceptor (or something like that) to restrain user
>   with default password only to work
>   with /changePassword.htm page. What is
>   the simplest solution?

One way (may not the simplest, and a one that **needs** documentation) is to give a user with the default passwort not the full set of priveleges (ony the privileges that he need to set the new password), after chaning tha password, give the user the full set of privileges, which allow him to do all the other stuff.

Comment: [1.] On a login page, where user isn't authenticated, locale interception also doesn't work (if you meant on that). [2.] I found RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(request); After that I could be able to get current locale Locale locale = RequestContext.getLocale(); The problem here is that variable request is an object of a HttpServletRequest class. I don't have idea where to set it. However, i just need simplest example to set and get locale from java class. Many thanks!

Comment: @Mario [1] - I meant: I guess the bug is, that your Security Interceptor "catches" the request to change the locale before the Local Change Interceptor can handle it. (easyset way to handle it, would be not to intercept the local change requests for the login page)

Comment: @Mario [2] - In your controller it is easy, (Spring 3.0) just add a HttpServletRequest parameter to you controller method, or that is also possible **simply add a parameter Locale local** to your controller method. (see added part of my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Try registering localeChangeInterceptor this way. It worked for me.

```
<mvc:interceptors>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
              <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
        </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```